# Identifying styles in PDF

Tags: fonts, pdf, templates, tools

It happens many times that I take a look at an interestingly typeset document in LaTeX, but to which I don't have the source-code to inspect the style. One such example is this one: http://philosophy.unimelb.edu.au/ajl/2011/2011_5.pdf

I know there are free services online that identify the fonts. They may be useful for simple text, but, for example, mathematics, it becomes very hard to identify the correct style.

So, my question is, what could one use to help reproducing a specific style when only having access to the final PDF?

Comment: Why not flatter the author into sharing his style file?

Comment: Because sometimes the author is not available. Or the typesetting was done by an editor.

Comment: @Emre: Please add such statements as comments, not as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For fonts, you can use `pdffonts`:

```
$ pdffonts charismanie.pdf 
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
BQFNPY+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT      CID TrueType      yes yes yes     59  0
UQUJMH+Centennial-Roman              CID TrueType      yes yes yes     60  0
NSOUSR+LinLibertine                  Type 1            yes yes no     137  0
NSOUSR+LinLibertine                  Type 1            yes yes no     138  0
PTKESR+LinLibertineI                 Type 1            yes yes no     143  0
TYFIDZ+CMSY10                        Type 1            yes yes no     144  0
MHUAJQ+LinLibertineB                 Type 1            yes yes no     145  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     146  0
QTAYVE+LinBiolinumB                  Type 1            yes yes no     161  0
CXJGOW+CMR12                         Type 1            yes yes no     207  0
PTKESR+LinLibertineI                 Type 1            yes yes no     285  0
PFIFSH+fourier-orns                  Type 1            yes yes no     465  0
```

**Edit:** pipitas provided a nice answer with the `-f` and `-l` options for `pdffonts`. In order to automate his suggestion a bit more to list fonts in a PDF, here is a little script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Parse options
RANGE=0
while getopts ":ap:f:l:g:" option; do
   case $option in
      a)
         RANGE=1
         ;;
      p)
         RANGE=1
         STARTPAGE=$OPTARG
         ENDPAGE=$STARTPAGE
         ;;
      f)
         RANGE=1
         STARTPAGE=$OPTARG
         ;;
      l)
         RANGE=1
         ENDPAGE=$OPTARG
         ;;
      g)
         GREP=1
         KEYWORD=$OPTARG
         ;;
      *)
         echo "Unknown option $option"
         exit 1
         ;;
  esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
PDF="$1"

if [ -z "$PDF" ]; then
   echo "E: You must provide a PDF file"
   exit 1
fi

PAGES=$(pdfinfo $PDF | awk '/^Pages:/ { print $2 }')


if [ $RANGE = 1 ]; then
   for p in $(seq ${STARTPAGE:-1} ${ENDPAGE:-$PAGES}); do
      echo "== Fonts on page $p/$PAGES =="
      pdffonts -f $p -l $p $PDF
   done
elif [ $GREP = 1 ]; then
   FOUND=""
   for p in $(seq ${STARTPAGE:-1} ${ENDPAGE:-$PAGES}); do
      pdffonts -f $p -l $p $PDF | grep -q "^${KEYWORD} " && \
         FOUND="$FOUND $p"
   done
   if [[ -n $FOUND ]]; then
      echo "The font $KEYWORD was found on the following pages:$FOUND"
   else
      echo "The font $KEYWORD was not found"
   fi
else
   pdffonts $PDF
fi
```

It is a bash script, to be used on *nix systems. Here, I saved it as `showfonts.sh`).

Here is what it does:

- Without any options, it just executes `pdffonts` on the given PDF file;
- The `-a` option (for `all`) does what pipitas suggested: it lists fonts on every page individually, e.g.:

  ```
  $ ./showfonts.sh -a charismanie.pdf
  ```
- The `-p` option (for `page`) lists fonts on a specific page of the PDF, e.g.:

  ```
  $ ./showfonts.sh -p 15 charismanie.pdf
  ```
- The `-f` and `-l` options (for `first` and `last`) are the equivalent of the same options in `pdffonts` (so `-f 1` is equivalent to `-a`), e.g.:

  ```
  $ ./showfonts.sh -f 13 -l 16 charismanie.pdf
  ```
- The `-g` option (for `grep`) lets you find on which pages a font is used, e.g.:

  ```
  $ ./showfonts.sh -g "LeagueGothic" charismanie.pdf
  ```

  It also also takes wildcards to match fonts with similar names, e.g.:

  ```
  $ ./showfonts.sh -g ".*Libertine.*" charismanie.pdf
  ```

This script is now committed on github: https://github.com/raphink/listpdffonts

Edit: The script now supports font subsets with `-g` as requested by Kurt Pfeifle. See Git repository.

Comment: Nice tip -- but are there any tools suitable for identifying on which page(s) / page-locations of the pdf an object can be found?

Comment: @Mark: see my answer below...

Comment: @Mark: Thanks to pipitas' suggestion, see my edited answer, in particular option `-g`.

Comment: Very nice script, Raphink :-)  You could put the icing on the cake by adding some more options:  (1) Add a `--help` option.  (2) Let `-g` also handle font subsets (which are marked by prefix to the main font name, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23104/using-and-interpreting-pdffonts/32189#32189 ) and print the respective messages.

Comment: @Raphink: are you considering my suggestion for you script?

Comment: @pipitas: Sorry, I didn't update the answer. Will do that later, and I might start a project on github for it.

Comment: @pipitas: I'm not sure to understand what you would like to do with font subsets. `-g` already allows to grep them since they are shown in the `name` field.

Comment: @Raphink: What I meant with the 'handling of subsets': (1) Assume a PDF which uses Arial.  (2) However, the font isn't fully embedded, but only as a *subset*.  (3) That means the fontname used in the PDF is not 'Arial' but something like 'ABCDEF+Arial'. -- Your script should be made to find anyway it when called with `-g Arial` (no Wildcard required).

Comment: @Raphink: Oh, and when using wildcards `-g .*Libertine.*` the result should print the full name of the found fonts...  :-)   Just for your wishlist :-)

Comment: Ok @KurtPfeifle. These are good ideas. Patches/PRs welcome :)

Comment: Just implemented them actually.

Answer (score 5):

For the fonts.
If viewing in **Adobe Reader**, right click, **Document Properties...**, then **Fonts**.

Answer (score 4):

@Mark:

If you want to know the fonts on page 3, use

```
pdffonts -f 3 -l 3 /path/to/pdf
```

(The `f` is for *first*, the `l` is for *last* page). If you want to know which font appears on which page of a 10-page PDF, use

```
for p in $(seq 1 10); do
    pdffonts -f ${p} -l ${p} /path/to/pdf
done
```

Above examples are for *nix OS. If you are on Windows, try

```
for %p in (1,1,10) do pdffonts -f %p -l %p
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice suggestion. I updated my answer to take that in consideration.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a in-house style for "The Australasian Journal of Logic". They require submissions as standard LaTeX documents using the article class, and the style file is not publicly available.

Comment: Yes, it is... And, for the record, the main text seems to be typed in Hoefler Text (11pt, 1.1 spacing) and the Math in Euler.